# Overlapping numbers

Tags: r

Say we have to different sets of data like:

```
A <- (1:20)
B <- (9:18)
```

Now to output the overlapping number the following can be used:

```
C <- A[B]
```

But what if we want the opposite. The following does not work:

```
C <- A[!B]
```

Why, and how can one output the unique values?

Comment: If `A` doesn't start with 1, your code won't give you the expected result.

Comment: Sure. Work  fine! Can you recommend any tutorial where one can learn the base R functions??

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/00Index.html But it's usually better to think about how a statistician would call such an operation and then use that as search terms.

Comment: `!B` is going to give you a vector of FALSE values. Rather use `-B` which will drop those indices from the A vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A[B] is just subsetting the vector A by the *positions* in vector B. If you want to use the actual values to get something like the intersection, you can to use the %in% operator.

This discrepancy is unclear using your example because A happens to have the same positions as it does elements, i.e. 1 is in position 1 and 20 is in position 20. Here is another example that shows this slight nuance:

```
A = (c(1:5, 8:20))
B= (1:10)
A[B]

A[A %in% B]
A[!(A %in% B)]
```